# exception (renderingEngine) 1.0.2 version

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

dear all,
I installed gazebo from source (debugging-modus), which I downloaded using the mercurial repository. It's the 1.0.2 version and I get some exceptions trying the gzserver command:

Exception [RenderEngine.cc:471] unable to find rendering system
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find rendering system
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:471] unable to find rendering system
Exception [Sensors.cc:39] Unable to load the rendering engine

Is this a problem of my system? Should I switch to the 1.0.1 version, if I'd like to create some plugins?

Thank you for your help.
Ferdinand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/53/exception-(renderingengine)-1.0.2-version/) by [FerdinandT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44/ferdinandt/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This problem occurs when Gazebo cannot find the RenderSystem_GL.so that is installed by Ogre.

I would recommend bypassing this issue by upgrading to Gazebo 1.2.3, which has some better logic to find and install the necessary dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0